# Normalizing the wave-function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, normalization

I want to show that the wave-function of
$$\Psi(x,0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 5 }}(2\psi_{2}(x)-\psi_{3}(x)) $$
for an infinite potential well of length $a$ is normalized. With the time-independent function of
$$\psi_{n}(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{a} }\sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{a}x \right)$$
where $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$.

My intuition tells me that if I were to normalize this function with the coefficient of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$, it should equal $1$.

I tried said method but ended up with $1 = \frac{3}{5}$. Could someone please enlighten me where I went wrong?

Comment: maybe because $2^2+1=5$?

Comment: In terms of kets you have $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(2|\psi_2\rangle - |\psi_3\rangle\right)$. And you also have $\langle \psi_i|\psi_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$. So your "intuitiion" was correct... $\langle \Psi|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{5}\left(4 + 1\right) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

To see that the function is normalized take its inner product with itself:
$$\begin{align}
|\Psi(x,0)|^2&={1\over 5}\int_{0}^{+a}(2\psi_2(x)^{*}-\psi_3(x)^{*})(2\psi_2(x)-\psi_3(x))\;dx\\
&={1\over 5}\int_{0}^{+a}(4|\psi_2|^2-2\psi_2^{*}\psi_3-2\psi_3^{*}\psi_2+|\psi_3|^2)\;dx\\
&={1\over 5}\int_{0}^{+a}\bigg[{8\over a}\sin^2({2\pi\over a}x)-{4\over a}\sin({2\pi\over a}x)\sin({3\pi\over a}x)+{2\over a}\sin^2({3\pi\over a}x)\bigg]\;dx.
\end{align}$$
If the wave function is normalized then the above integral should reduce to $|\Psi(x,0)|^2=1$, otherwise the wave function is not normalized.